# hide currently selected listbox element - works with mozilla not with chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, hide

On the web page I have a listbox with a few items in it.
The line:

```
    $('#my-list-of-options option:selected').hide();
```

successfully hides the element currently selected element in mozilla. Not in *chrome* though. How can I get it to work in chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:none` does not work across browser for `option`. You can try to make the option `disabled`

```
 $('#my-list-of-options option:selected').prop('disabled',true);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tPaj/)

Or remove the option and rebind it when required. Save it in the select `data` for latter restore, something like this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ufxt/)

Comment: That does disable the option but it's still visible. Ideally I'd like to make it disappear altogether but without physically removing it from the list.

Comment: Yes thats what disabled do. try the second solution.

Comment: This may not be the answer you wanted, but its the correct one.

Comment: @Ya. also if you want to restore a particular option you can easily apply selector on the stored `data` and extract it out, or filter out the unwanted and populate them.

Comment: I intended to mark yours.

Comment: @Ya. ok. I was wondering what went wrong and what you were expecting.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The css display:none on option elements is not supported in chrome (or ie).

The only choice is to remove the element:

```
$('#toppings').change(function(){
    var selected = $('#toppings option:selected');    
    selected.remove();    
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/777Jm/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great refcard on [jQuery selectors](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors) (though may have to sign up to download it).

```
$('#my-list-of-options option[selected]').hide();
```